# How to get data from service in android

Tags: android

Hi just a newbie with android. I am trying to create a service which will constantly fetch location and update the an activity exp: Dashboard map. I have been following [Android service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Now my problem is how to
- Constantly notify Dashboard activity ( was trying to simulate with while loop to notify data) from service
- I was able to print logs on connect and onBind, but i was wondering how to constantly watch for notification from service and retrieve the notified data from the Activity ie.Dashboard. Hope I am able convey my issue. I am searching for the latest api.

Answer (score 0):

You should use BroadcastReceiver in your Dashboard activity. to do this follow this step:

Add a inner class to Dashboard activity like this:

```
public class ActionCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String state = "disconnected";
        if(intent != null)
            state = intent.getStringExtra("State");
        //Your Code
    }
}
```

Add this code to Dashboard activity:

```
private ActionCompleteReceiver mActionReceiver;
public static final String ACTION_SERVICE_COMPLETE = "YUOR_PACKAGE_NAME.ACTION_SERVICE_COMPLETE";
```

Register receiver in onResume method in Dashboard activity like this

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if(mActionReceiver = null)
        mActionReceiver= new ActionCompleteReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mActionReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_SERVICE_COMPLETE));
}
```

Unregister receiver onPause and onDestroy:

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();

    if (mActionReceiver != null)
    {
        try
        {
            unregisterReceiver(mActionReceiver );
        }
        catch (Exception ignored)
        {
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();

    if (mActionReceiver != null)
    {
        try
        {
            unregisterReceiver(mActionReceiver );
        }
        catch (Exception ignored)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

In your service where you need to notify Dashboard activity  add this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DashboardActivity.ACTION_SERVICE_COMPLETE);
intent.putExtra("State", "Connected");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Yes this works perfectly fine... and was able to deliver message from service to dashboard... thanks. But on the other note, when should we be using the mechanism of Notification as mention in the link [Android service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). Any advantage and disadvantage of the mention mechanism. As i can understand is if an operation takes more than 5 seconds, then ANR is encountered... Might be we are doing this to avoid ANR. I may be wrong, just a thought.